# WPF: DataContext dependency property in non - GUI - classes?

Tags: wpf, datacontext, dependency-properties

Is it possible to have a dependency property "DataContext" in a class that is NOT derived from "FrameworkElement" (but it can be derived from "DependencyObject")?

I already tried and created a class (which I added to Window.Resources), but the DataContext is always null.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The future plan is to use XAML with databinding but without WPF. And if I get this done I may even provide a very nice open source - framework doing that.

Think out of the box - I will use XAML as an object creation tool, utilizing data binding, but (as I said) not with WPF.

And I will fill a niche people didn't even think it does exist, hehehe... however, the few people I showed my idea so far were stunned.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I know that there are non-FrameworkElement (and non-FrameworkContentElement) classes that can "inherit" their parent's DataContext for purposes of binding. For example, in WPF 4, you can bind the Command property of InputBinding, and it uses its parent's DataContext. See: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/vs2010-binding-support-in-inputbindings/ Perhaps you could dig into this and see if it suggests anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the AddOwner method?
Example (FrameworkContentElement):

```
DataContextProperty = FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(FrameworkContentElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, new PropertyChangedCallback(FrameworkContentElement.OnDataContextChanged)));
```

If you leave out the callback/options .. it might work.